# Standard Error and Standard Deviations

Tags: statistics

How it s possible to calculate standard error for single sample, While standard error is defined as variance in different sample means?

Comment: When you say "single sample", do you mean a sample size $n\gt 1$ taken once or a sample size $n=1$?

Comment: n is number of observations in a sample. It may be any number, by 'single sample' I mean only one sample is taken from population

Answer (score 0):

The population has a (presumably unknown) variance.  If you take a sample of size $n$ with replacement then the variance of the sample mean is $\frac1n$ times the population variance.  Taking the square root gives the standard deviation.

You can calculate the mean of the sample as an estimate of the population mean, though it is unlikely to be exactly correct. You can also estimate the population variance from the sample, at least if not all the samples give the same value, so taking the square root of $\frac1n$ times this variance estimate gives an estimate of the standard error of the mean.

Comment: Why we take square root of ¹/n to estimate population variance. Why not just ¹/n.

Comment: I'm not getting the ¹/n stuff. What if we take a sample of 50 from population of 500, then according to you sample mean will be ¹/50 times population mean, how it is possible?

Comment: @RahulSingh:  Not quite.  if $\hat V$ is the estimate of the population variance, then $\frac{1}{n} \hat V$ is the estimate of the variance of the sample mean and the square root of that, i.e. $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \hat V}$, is the estimate of the standard error of the mean.  So if $n=50$ I am saying that (sampling with replacement) the variance of the sample mean is $\frac1{50}$ of the population variance

Comment: Sorry sir, but I'm not getting this what you say, "$\frac{1}{n} \hat V$ is the estimate of the variance of the sample mean" .

Comment: @RahulSingh If one sample observation $X$ from the population has variance $V$, then the sum of $n$ i.i.d. samples has variance $nV$, and so the mean of $n$ i.i.d. samples ($\frac1n$ times the sum) has variance  $\frac1{n^2} nV = \frac1nV$

Comment: Thank you so much sir, double cleared.